# Osmnx plotting multiple graph routes

Tags: python, osmnx

If I plot each route on different map the result is perfect. However, what I want is to plot multiple route on single map.

My code is:

```
import osmnx as ox, networkx as nx, matplotlib.pyplot as plt, math as m
from haversine import haversine

org = (27.5075, 77.6779)
dst = (27.5067, 77.6694)
dist_fl = (int(haversine(org, dst)*1000))*2
G = ox.graph_from_point(org, simplify=False, distance=dist_fl)
orig_node = ox.get_nearest_node(G, org, method='euclidean')
target_node = ox.get_nearest_node(G, dst, method='euclidean')

nodes, edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G)
streets_per_node = ox.count_streets_per_node(G)
route = nx.shortest_path(G, source=orig_node, target=target_node, 
weight='length', method='dijkstra')
node_route = nodes.loc[route]

route_list = [[1352186296, 1352186345], [1352186345, 1352186150, 1350260490, 
1352186112, 1352186349, 1350260516, 4753659536L, 4753498382L], [4753498382, 
4753498383L, 4753498390L], [4753498390, 4753498391L, 4753498392L, 
4753498393L, 4753498394L], [4753498394, 4753498395L, 4753498396L, 
4753498397L, 4753498398L], [4753498398, 4753478108L], [4753478108, 
4753498399L, 4753498400L, 4753498401L], [4753498401, 4753498402L, 
4753498403L], [4753498403, 4753498404L, 4753498405L, 4753657826L, 
4753498406L, 4753498407L, 4753498408L, 4753498409L], [4753498409, 4753498410L, 4753498411L, 4753498412L], [4753498412, 3803339674L], [3803339674, 1352186110, 1352186253, 2265692728L], [2265692728, 1352186308, 1352186133, 1352186328, 1352186316, 1352186071, 1352186187, 1352186095], [1352186095, 1352186361, 1352186263]]

coord_list =[(77.6776527, 27.5069438), (77.6775911, 27.5061476), (77.6747421, 27.5061048), (77.6747447, 27.5065153), (77.6742216, 27.5065135), (77.6741438, 27.507339), (77.6740672, 27.5073159), (77.6738192, 27.5079793), (77.6736687, 27.5079667), (77.6726402, 27.5084229), (77.6720677, 27.5081814), (77.6717673, 27.5093129), (77.6704672, 27.5094812), (77.6690214, 27.507629)]

color_list = ['green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'red', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'red', 'red']

fig, ax = ox.plot_graph_routes(G, route_list, fig_height=10, fig_width=10, save=True, filename='outfile_data', show=False, close=False, axis_off=False, edge_linewidth=1, node_size=10, route_color = color_list)

plt.show()
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

A route is consists of multiple lines. You have to create a list of colours for each line in the route. Then change the colour for the next route for number of lines it has. E.g. If you have two routes lets say sp1 and sp2 those contains the consecutive OSMids, then, you have to write something like:

```
c1 = (len(sp1)-1) * ['r']
c2 = (len(sp2)-1) * ['g']
color_list = c1 + c2
ox.plot.plot_graph_routes(G,[sp1,sp2],route_color = color_list)
```

--------------------- replace the color list by the following code----

```
list_of_colors = [ 'green', 'purple', 'black', 'blue', 'yellow', 'red', 'orange'] ## add more colour if you have more routes

color_list = []

for i in range(len(route_list)):
    num_lines = len(route_list[i]) - 1
    color_elements = num_lines * [list_of_colors[i]]
    color_list.expand(color_elements)

print(color_list)
ox.plot.plot_graph_routes(G,route_list,route_color = color_list)
```